# user data for managed node group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

How can I edit user data in the managed node group which is part of my EKS cluster?
I tried to create a new version for the Launch Template that EKS cluster has created but I get an error on "Health issues" of the cluster: **Ec2LaunchTemplateVersionMismatch**
I want to make the nodes in the managed node group to mount the EFS automatically, without doing it manually on each instance, because of the autoscaling.